# OTA updates for Device Owner Android Application(Kiosk mode)

Tags: android, nfc, updates, kiosk-mode, device-owner

I am able to make my app, the device owner app through NFC as mentioned [here](http://sdgsystems.com/blog/implementing-kiosk-mode-android-part-3-android-lollipop/). Now I want to update my app over the air, but I couldn't find a method **without rooting**.

Google is providing many options for enterprises to develop apps as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Enterprise), but nowhere providing a way to update the application through OTA.

Looking for a solution.

Comment: Evolve ( https://github.com/VivekPanyam/Evolve ) might be helpful

Comment: I already saw that but unable to use it, also it is in alpha phase , which might get our app crashed. It seems to change the code at run time, so looks a bit complicated.

Comment: @Shubham did you get this working?

Comment: @Maragues 2 years back, without rooting I wasn't abe to do it.

Comment: @Shubham thanks a lot, that's why I thought. Unfortunately my client still has lots of 4.4.2 devices :(

Answer (score 4):

This is just pure speculation as I've never tried to use the package installer API myself:

You could try to set an installer package for your device owner app (using `PackageManager.setInstallerPackageName()`). This installer package would need to be a separate APK signed with the same certificate as the device owner APK.

```
getPackageManager().setInstallerPackage("<device.owner.package.name>", "<installer.package.name>");
```

From your installer APK, you could then use `PackageInstaller` to prepare an update:

```
PackageInstaller pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
int sessId = pi.createSession(new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL));
PackageInstaller.Session session = pi.openSession(sessId);
OutputStream out = session.openWrite("app");
// .. write updated APK file to out
session.fsync(out);
session.commit(...);
session.close();
```

I'm not sure if this silently installs your update though (or if that works at all in the way I would have expected).

Comment: @Shubham In case you try that approach, I would be really happy for feedback if that works as I had expected (or if not what problems you experienced).

Comment: I couldn't try your answer but did some more research on Package Installer and found out that for committing a session we will be needing root permissions. I will still try this soon and give you a feedback.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884956/how-to-install-update-remove-apk-using-packageinstaller-class-in-android-l

Answer (score 1):

Create a service to background check for update. if update available download apk file and write it on some where like sdcard. wait some seconds to write completely flush. then call following code to install your new apk.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

`fileName` is path of your new apk file on sd card.

Comment: I want to do that silently.Your method will not install the apk silently.This will open the install UI and also will have to check in setting "allow installs from unknown sources"

Answer (score 1):

You could use Play Store to provide updates for your app:

1. Provision device owner app through NFC, just as you already did.
2. Provide an updated version (same package name, same signature, higher version number) of your device owner app on Play Store.
3. In the Play Store app on your device, search for your Play Store version of the app and install the update.
4. Activate auto-updates for your device owner app in Play Store (on the Play Store page of your app, click menu (three dots) and activate the checkbox for auto-update.

That's quite some effort for the provisioning phase, but the device should receive future updates automatically.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I thought of the same thing but that would need a gmail account to be set up on the device which I was avoiding as the application is meant for KIOSK mode.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might want to become an EMM/MDM partner app-it is similar to device owner app but with enhanced privileges and APIs. Normally OEMs like Samsung/HTC provides hidden APIs to the MDM partner apps for upgrading apps.I am not sure whether  Android for Work also provides this api.

For eg: OEMs provides an api called updatePackage(String packageName) which can be use by MDM client on the device to update the package.You can use this API to update the Device Owner App too.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this question and wanted to add that the answer of a question from a link in the comments has been expanded and it is now possible to silently install the app, as long as your App is Device Owner:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37153867/7173050

Here the part, from Android 6.0 and up:
Once your app gets the Device owner permission, we can install, uninstall and update silently without any user intervention.

```
public static boolean installPackage(Context context, InputStream in, String packageName) throws IOException {
    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
    PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
        PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
    params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
    // set params
    int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
    PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
    OutputStream out = session.openWrite("COSU", 0, -1);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, c);
    }
    session.fsync(out);
    in.close();
    out.close();

    session.commit(createIntentSender(context, sessionId));
    return true;
}



private static IntentSender createIntentSender(Context context, int sessionId) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
             context, sessionId, new Intent(ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE), 0);
    return pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
}
```

Uninstall:

```
String appPackage = "com.your.app.package";
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), getActivity().getClass());
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
PackageInstaller mPackageInstaller = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
mPackageInstaller.uninstall(appPackage, sender.getIntentSender());
```

And last but not least the link:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageInstallerSession.java