# How to install android apk using PackageInstaller and DeviceOwner

Tags: android

I was researching and found that through the classes PackageInstaller, which is from api 21, it is possible to install third-party applications without user interaction.
I am based on this example that is published in github:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc

I have not been able to make it work, I also read that it is necessary that your application works as Device Owner of the device.

I found this code in more than one site, but I could not make it work, it does not generate error when sending the PendingIntent.

Here is the example code:

```
public static boolean installPackage(Context context, InputStream in, String packageName)
        throws IOException {
    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
    PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
    params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
    // set params
    int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
    PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
    OutputStream out = session.openWrite("COSU", 0, -1);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, c);
    }
    session.fsync(out);
    in.close();
    out.close();

    session.commit(createIntentSender(context, sessionId));
    return true;
}

private static IntentSender createIntentSender(Context context, int sessionId) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            sessionId,
            new Intent(ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE),
            0);
    return pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
}
```

I try this with the app package that I want to install, but doesn't seems to work.
If anyone can I will be very grateful.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37153867/878126 ?