# Can System App access /data/data of other apps

Tags: android, root, super

I am developing an app for the custom device. My app run from `/system/priv-apps`

I need to access `/data/data` for other apps to give a cloud backup functionality.

While searching I came across **"android.permission.CONFIRM_FULL_BACKUP"** permission but I couldn't find a way to get the content of that particular "`/data/data/pkg_name`".

I don't think that system apps have **su** permission so I can't call `cp -R src dest`

Can anyone tell me regarding this?

Comment: What is the "custom device"? Can you clarify which hardware you use?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have partnered with a Device Manufacturer Company to have my app in  /system/priv-apps folder

Comment: I think system apps can access the /data/data folder

Comment: @JyotiJK When I tried writing f.exists() for some file in data/data/ folder it says that file exists but while copying it throws java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Permission denied)

Comment: Did you get root permission before accessing it?

Comment: @JyotiJK No, Just want to confirm one thing that Since this app will be preinstalled (As System App) on Devices which are not rooted! So, su command won't be available for those users? Please let me know if I am wrong!

Comment: @Maragues Can you help in this context ?

Comment: I have no clue, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a System app is very different from being an App with a root permission.
If you deployed your app as a system app after partnership from OEM this does not mean you will get root access.

System app is nothing but base apk installed in another location  which cannot be uninstalled. Other than that it has some permission privileges.

**But that does not mean it can access to data/data of other apps.**

So, in short answer is a NO. You need a root access which user has to do by flashing a rom, and after installing binaries. Post that if that user provides SU access then an only then you can access data/data of other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Being in the same scenario as you fellow, my system app cant read nothing inside /data/data

Logcat:
W  type=1400 audit(0.0:121): avc: denied { read } for name="data" dev="vdc" ino=122881 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0