# How do I install apps or apk into data/app directory in an AOSP build?

Tags: android, apk, android-source

I am looking to add a prebuilt APK to AOSP build using the emulator. I successfully installed an APK into *system/app* directory by doing the related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579827/how-do-i-add-apks-in-an-aosp-build).

But I want to add an APK into *data/app* directory.

My development environments are followings:
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- AOSP: android 6.0.1_r77
- AOSP emulator

I tried the following steps by the several related questions.

1. Add the APK to the */packages/apps* directory.
2. Create an Android.mk file.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_MODULE := <name of APK>

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <Name of APK>.apk

LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS

LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_DATA)

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

3. Add  in */build/target/product/core.mk*

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \ <name of APK>
```

The above Android.mk file didn't even install the APK into *system/app*.
And I also tried the followings. The following make files installed the APK into *system/app*.

```
...

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests

...
```

```
...

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_DATA_APPS)

...
```

```
...

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/data/app

...
```

I expect to install the APK into */data/app* folder.

Answer (score 2):

*There might be a better way*, but the way I handled was by including the *.apk* in a system directory ( not installing it, just use **PRODUCT_COPY_FILES** ).

Add in your `device.mk` code like this to copy the file:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    vendor/XXXXX/common/apps/MYApplication/MYApplication.apk:system/app/MYApplication.nm
```

Then modify **Provision** app ( which runs on first device boot ) to install that APK. The installation is done via **PackageManager** API. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45799826/3801327), or similar.

Comment: please explain your method with an example

Comment: Hi @Mneckoee
I added some more details in the answer, hope it helps